# Reload UICollectionView Footer Size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

Im trying to accomplish a comment `UITextView` similar to Instagrams. I previously did this with `UITableView` and used `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` to reload the footer size as the user enter their comments. With my `collectionView` I've tried a few different ways to reload my footer but the view scrolls up to its original position, hiding the textView under the keyboard. Im trying to keep the `UITextView` above the keyboard and have it expand for each new line.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
        NSInteger numLines;
        numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
        if (numLines > nextLine) {
            height = height + 15;
            [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
            [footer.commentTextView becomeFirstResponder];
            CGPoint scrollPt = CGPointMake(0, 300);
            [self.collectionView setContentOffset:scrollPt animated:NO];

            nextLine = numLines;
   }
}

 - (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return CGSizeMake(320, height);
}
```